# Ionic 2 Images not displaying on device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

It just seems the simplest of things such as using the correct url path for an image can consume so much time and effort with no success at all.

So, in my homepage I tried to use one of the following:

```
<img src="../assets/img/image.jpg"/>
<img src="/assets/img/image.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/img/image.jpg"/>
<img src="./assets/img/image.jpg"/>
<img src="../../assets/img/image.jpg"/>
```

All of which display on the browser and but not on the device.

I've read so many threads and it is disgraceful that yet there is no real solution to this. I would really like to know what it is I am doing wrong here? Any helps and real solutions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Watch your casing as well! Some devices have case sensitive file systems. that's caught me in the past when I deployed an ionic app to a device and resources couldn't be found.

Comment: `it is disgraceful that yet there is no real solution to this` +1 +1 +1

Comment: The real solution I feel is: make all your paths like src="assets/img/image.jpg" and once you do that everywhere in your app src, do build:  ionic cordova build ... This will make sure that images appear on the next run.

Comment: none of below suggestions worked for me so far

Comment: Dumb mistake trying to get Ionic project to work on another computer - the `www` folder isn't tracked in git and gets rebuilt, not copied, so the `/images` and `data` directories that were working fine on one machine don't exist on the current one. Have to transfer them, but not at 6pm on a Friday - I quit and am going home.

Answer (score 52):

I had the same issue with relative paths

```
<img src="../assets/img/vis_reco.png">
```

does work with ionic serve / and also with livereload in the emulator (e.g. from src/pages/home/home.html ) **But not on the device.**

Don't use relative paths for images !!!

```
<img src="assets/img/vis_reco.png">
```

works for me with Ionic (v3) and also angular typescript apps.
On the device (`ionic cordova run`)  with `ionic serve`  and also with `ng s` (angular apps)

used dir tree:

[image: used dir tree]

you can see an (official) example in the ionic conference starter, try:

```
ionic start ionicConf conference
```

(btw: same quetiosn & answer here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/images-not-displayed-on-device/89145 )

Answer (score 49):

You don't need to use `../assets/`. Just specify path from `assets/img/`.

For images in your CSS `(background-image, border-image, etc.)`, you need to use `../assets/`.

Once you build the app, the file structure will be like,

```
 assets/
    img/
       img1.jpg
       img2.jpg

 build/
    main.css
    polyfills.js
    main.js

 index.html
```

HTML will be dynamically added to `index.html`. So src of `img` tag, will be from same location of the `index.html` file. So, `assets/img/*.jpg` is enough for src of `img` tag. Coming to *CSS* file, the *assets* folder is a folder back to the its location. So, for using image in CSS like, `background-image`, `border-image` etc. we need to specify the path like, `../assets/img/*.jpg`.

Comment: DomSanitizer should be imported from `'@angular/platform-browser'`. Anyways, it didn't work for me

Comment: Works as a fix for ionic view too. Thanks

Comment: Why do we need to use `../assets/` for `background-image`? I see it works like a charm, but still, I do not understand why `assets/` does not.

Comment: @PiotrekDe, While serving app using ionic serve the CSS file looks for files root directory. But, after building app, CSS loads images from relative path from its location.

Comment: @Harish But I use the `assets/` for all other image references than `background-image`, for example for `img`s or `link rel="icon"` and it works fine for them. So I was really surprised that it doesn't work for `background-url`. Maybe I did not copy resources correctly and dist is busted... It should work exactly the same for `background-image` CSS and `img` in HTML.

Comment: __This is the correct answer.__  Everything else in this thread is either SPAM or incomplete/misleading.  To keep your IDE happy (i.e. to avoid _Cannot resolve directory 'assets'_ warnings) you should use symbolic links.  I.e. this will work to resolve those warnings for all SCSS files in your pages directory: (from your main project directory) `ln -s $(pwd)/src/assets $(pwd)/src/pages`

Answer (score 9):

Add your images to `src/assets/imgs directory`

Set image path in HTML like

```
<img src="assets/imgs/example.jpg">
```

Set image path in SCSS like

```
background-image: url(../assets/imgs/example.jpg);
```

It will work browser, emulator and build

Answer (score 2):

My problem was uppercase in the name of the file in the folder..
Checking it out now

[image]

Comment: it didn't do the trick.
the most weard thing is that other images i can see on the device

Answer (score 2):

In Ionic (v3) it should work, its works for me.

```
<img src="assets/img/image.jpg">
```

**Additional**

If your image URL is dynamic then you can use property binding, sometimes it does not work on the real device when we use img src like-

```
    <img src="{{imageUrl}}">
```

then it works in the browser but in the real device sometimes it does not work, so here is another way we use property binding-

```
    <img [src]="imageUrl">
```

it is work on the real device.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but solved by the path from relative to absolute and it is working now . I would like to share my experience as well that I have not changed the angular file which requires the img location lolx it was funny but I did it so also look your HTML page as well.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution I feel is: make all your paths like src="assets/img/image.jpg" and once you do that everywhere in your app src, do build: ionic cordova build ... This will make sure that images appear on the next run.

Answer (score 1):

Image not showing for `ionic cordova build android` I am found this solution in **Ionic 3**.

try this:

```
<img src="/android_asset/www/assets/imgs/avatar.png" alt="Loading...">
```

it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, images are displayed fine on browser and real app by putting the images not in asset but in www/img and accessing them in the html files with:

```
<img src="img/filename.png" />
```

Comment: Having tried that, the images do not show in browser. Also by putting them in the www folder, will they not get wiped?

Comment: Strange. I checked again, and based on the 1st answer here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/where-should-i-put-images/41463 that should work (even though things seems to have changed a bit with Ionic 2 RC0). And the images are not wiped when building since not in the build directory.
Are you referencing your image in the CSS or directly in the html? In the debugger console of your browser, do you have any error message?

Comment: I've tried both options, reference in CSS first with no luck then into html and still no different.

Answer (score 0):

Add your image under src/app/assets/   folder

call like below

```
    <img src="assets/img/bjork-live.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Are you putting assets folder in app folder? As the assets folder is its own directory under src.

Comment: under the src/app/ folder there is assets folder. it is default in ionic2 (In fresh installation you will find it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing the image from a html template then you use
`<img src="assets/img/mypic.png">`
it worked for me ionic v3

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue also, and resolved it by referencing all image sources in template files as if they were being rendered from the index.html file in the "src" directory.

```
<img src="assets/path_to_img_file_in_assets_folder">
```

The reason why this works when using "ionic serve" but not after building for a device is that "ionic serve" uses a local http server therefore the files end up being requested as **"http://localhost:port_number/assets/path_to_file"** (which is correct). However after the apk is built for a device, no local server is used, and the files are inaccessible because the template is rendered from the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I solved it in the following way, make sure that in the details of the image the file is like .jpg or .JPG this may seem simple, but do a test and you will see that the problem will be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more thing to the answers above - this was a problem for me twice already and I had to learn it the hard way both times.

So, in case you add a subfolder, for example, "Test" into your assets path and build an application, folder Test will be created in "www" folder.

If you later rename the folder inside src/ to "test" (notice the lower case t), the name inside "www" will stay as "Test" (notice the uppercase t) and images will load normally inside a browser (if you use ionic serve). But if you run it on the android device, the thing won't work (images won't display). So, you have to manually rename folders also inside www folder.

This "problem" persists on Windows, not sure for Linux/Mac OS but I have a feeling that this problem won't happen there since uppercase T won't be treated equally as lowercase T.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the images to asset folder.

**ex:assets/img/admin.png.**

in the above path working perfectly. My image available in Asset folder inside img folder inside I have image so getting in the above method. **Dont use ..asset/img.**.

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me after adding this in the `<head>` of the HTML document.

```html
<head>
        <base href="./">
</head>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<img src="./assets/img/image.jpg"/>
```

Because all the template of the components will be add into index.html, therefore, the image resource path is relative to the index.html, not relative to the template file

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), because they don't teach the solution.